# Fields tied to the state doesn't clear on successful form submission

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a contact form, when the form submission is successful it should clear the form field name, email and message which is tied up to the state. The form submission is successful but form fields name, email and message doesn't clear.

For test purpose what I'm doing is passing default values to the state but this values doesn't get filled in form during initial load.

```
export default function Contact() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('John Doe')
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('me@example.com')
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('Hello, this is test message.')

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const form = {"name": name, "email": email, "message": message}
    return fetch('/api/contact', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(form),
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    }).then(response => {
      if(response.status === 200){
        setName('')
        setEmail('')
        setMessage('')
      } else {
      }
    }).catch(err => err)
  }
  
  return (
      <section>
        <form method='post'>
          <div>
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" onChange={(e) => {setName(e.target.value)}}/>
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>Email Address</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" onChange={(e) => {setEmail(e.target.value)}}/>
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>Message</label>
            <textarea minLength={5} maxLength={2000} rows="6" name="message" onChange={(e) => {setMessage(e.target.value)}}></textarea>
          </div>
          <div>
            <button type='submit' onClick={(e) => {onSubmit(e)}}>Send Message</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </section>
  );
}
```

Comment: You didn't set the value prop for the inputs. For example, for the name input it should be `value={name}`.

Answer (score 0):

As User456 said, you need to add `value={variable}` for every `<input />`.
Example:

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Contact() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("John Doe");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("me@example.com");
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("Hello, this is test message.");

  const onSubmit = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setName("");
    setEmail("");
    setMessage("");
  };

  return (
    <section>
      <form method="post">
        <div>
          <label>Name</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="name"
            value={name}
            onChange={e => {
              setName(e.target.value);
            }}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Email Address</label>
          <input
            type="email"
            name="email"
            value={email}
            onChange={e => {
              setEmail(e.target.value);
            }}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Message</label>
          <textarea
            minLength={5}
            maxLength={2000}
            name="message"
            value={message}
            onChange={e => {
              setMessage(e.target.value);
            }}></textarea>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button
            type="submit"
            onClick={e => {
              onSubmit(e);
            }}>
            Send Message
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </section>
  );
}
```